# How Can I Parse an XML file using XmlNodeList

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode

I have been tasked with taking one XML file and converting it to a new XML I have no experience working with XML documents but I have been able to get some of the data from the first XML document using the code shown below. Note not all code is being shown just a small example.

```
XmlDocument rssXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        // Load the RSS file from the RSS URL
        rssXmlDoc.Load("https://agency.governmentjobs.com/jobfeed.cfm?agency=ocso");

        // Setup name space
        XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(rssXmlDoc.NameTable);
        nsmgr.AddNamespace("joblisting", "http://www.neogov.com/namespaces/JobListing");

        // Parse the Items in the RSS file
        XmlNodeList rssNodes = rssXmlDoc.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item/");

        // Iterate through the items in the RSS file
        foreach (XmlNode rssNode in rssNodes)
        {

            XmlNode rssSubNode = rssNode.SelectSingleNode("title");
            string title = rssSubNode != null ? rssSubNode.InnerText : "";
```

using this code I am able to get most of the elements.  I have run into a wall when trying to get data from a child element.  The portion of the XML I cannot get is shown below.

```
<joblisting:department>Supply</joblisting:department>
                <guid isPermaLink="true">https://www.governmentjobs.com/careers/ocso/Jobs/2594527</guid>
                <joblisting:categories>
                      <joblisting:category xmlns:joblisting="http://www.neogov.com/namespaces/JobListing" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
                        <CategoryCode>ClericalDataEntry</CategoryCode>
                        <Category>Clerical &amp; Data Entry</Category>
                      </joblisting:category>
                      <joblisting:category 
                </joblisting:categories>
```

But I cannot get all of the data. How can I get the value for the element that starts with guid isPermaLink="true"

For the joblisting:categories I have used a foreach loop to read those values

```
foreach (var item in rssSubNode.SelectNodes("joblisting:categories", nsmgr))
            {
                rssSubNode = rssSubNode = rssNode.SelectSingleNode("joblisting:category", nsmgr);
                string category = rssSubNode != null ? rssSubNode.InnerText : "";
            }
```

How can read the values of those child elements?

Comment: "...taking one XML file and converting it to a new XML..." is much better and easier to implement by using XSLT transformation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read guid node you can use the follow code. note that use selectSingleNode in node contains the "item" node.

```
public static void test() {
    XmlDocument rssXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    // Load the RSS file from the RSS URL
    rssXmlDoc.Load("https://agency.governmentjobs.com/jobfeed.cfm?agency=ocso");

    // Setup name space
    XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(rssXmlDoc.NameTable);
    nsmgr.AddNamespace("joblisting", "http://www.neogov.com/namespaces/JobListing");

    // Parse the Items in the RSS file
    XmlNodeList rssNodes = rssXmlDoc.SelectNodes("rss/channel/item");


    // Iterate through the items in the RSS file
    foreach (XmlNode rssNode in rssNodes) {
        var xmlnode = rssNode.SelectSingleNode("guid ");
        System.Console.WriteLine("the value of guid is =>" + xmlnode.InnerText);

        XmlNode rssSubNode = rssNode.SelectSingleNode("title");
        string title = rssSubNode != null ? rssSubNode.InnerText : "";
    }
}
```

Comment: And to read childnodes you can use  foreach (XmlNode rssNodechild in rssNodes.ChildNodes)